# Text overflowing out of div using transform: rotate(xdeg)

Tags: html, css, transform

Using the css attribute `transform: rotate();` works fine but when using it under horizontally oriented text it displayed outside of the `div` but I want it to display it within. I tried a lot with the `display`, `position`, `left`, `top`, `float` etc. attribute but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Here is the css-code for the vertical text:

```
width:130px;
height:50px;
-ms-transform:rotate(270deg); /* IE 9 */
-moz-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Firefox */
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform:rotate(270deg); /* Opera */
```

Here is the example to try:
http://jsfiddle.net/ty6Zj/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) property for that

```
transform-origin: 40px 20px;
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ty6Zj/2/)

---

Note: You've used all proprietary declarations for `transform`, should use a standard one as well..

```
transform:rotate(270deg);
```

Also, make sure you have this at the *end* of the proprietary properties...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I used 60px 60px and now it's displayed where it should be. I don't know how the calculation works but as long as it works I'm fine ;)

Comment: @user2718671 It's complicated on first sight, that's why I've linked the property to MDN documentation, you can refer the explanation there :)