# How to align text one by one vertically in div?

Tags: html, css

I need to create a fixed menu button which would be assigned to the right side of the browser. Currently i my code looks lie this:

```
#button-side-menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #363636;
    height: 28px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 16px;
    top: 91px;
    z-index: 2000;
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

[image]

Is it possible to center it in the div, the text was not adhered to the right side. And also is it possible to set test like this:

```
M
e
n
u
```

P.S.
Site is multilingual so i need the text, not image in this case.

Comment: James, as far as I can tell, this isn't a duplicate. The duplicate asks if it's possible, whereas this one wants to center it. Two different questions.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly this isn't a duplicate

Comment: Hmm, I've reopened it. Although I'm sure both of your questions have been previously answered here before. At any rate, the answer I had marked this as a duplicate of does answer the vertical text request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080792/how-can-i-draw-vertical-text-with-css-cross-browser

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21727403/1542290

Comment: I created a codepen a while back with vertical text - check it http://codepen.io/lukeocom/pen/mHnvl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
#button-side-menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    color: #363636;
    width: 15px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 16px;
    top: 91px;
    z-index: 2000;
    word-wrap:break-word;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Important: word-wrap and text-align are added to make it look like what you asked.
 Its width is fixed to 15px instead of height.

Comment: thanks, but still it is assigned to the right side of the dif, how to center it?

Comment: Please give some more code. This one is working individually for a single div containing this prescribed text. Check it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rDHfa

Comment: just add to your example `box-sizing: content-box;` and this will fix the problem in some cases.